# Sort columns based on the order inside SQL in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a query like the one below and i want records to be returned in the same order as the id's specified inside the 'in' function.

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 where id in(12,6,4,3,13)
```

Can i do this using sql alone or do i need to write my own sorting function.

Comment: Insert them into a temp table or table valued parameter with two columns. `id` and `SortOrder` and join rather than use `in`. Then you can just order by the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `CASE` to custom sort the records,

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 12 THEN 1
              WHEN ID = 6 THEN 2
              WHEN ID = 4 THEN 3
              WHEN ID = 3 THEN 4
              WHEN ID = 13 THEN 5
              ELSE 6
         END, ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1362d/2)

Comment: thats fine for now..but i have query of my own if `in` list is not fixed  than is there any way that we can sort according to list?

Comment: is the solution scalable? to say like 100-10k ids?

Comment: @AmitSingh then you can create dynamic sql for this or create a statement in your application level that generates the conditional ordering.

Comment: @JW웃 i think this would work. I  am doing paging on the server side of my web application, so instead getting all the data at once i can get only what is required to show on that particular page. Though now i can't cache the results anymore.

Comment: @thunderbird An `in` list of 10,000 items is not a good idea in itself.

Comment: @MartinSmith whatshould be used if you have to compare that many ids?

Comment: @thunderbird the docs suggest you should store them in a table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith i've been puzzling with this one, does `ORDER BY` clause  really uses `INDEX`?

Comment: If there is an index on the thing that you are ordering by it often will retrieve the rows in index order to avoid a sort. The plan will have ordered=true on the index scan.

Comment: @MartinSmith since i will be paging the data retrieving all 10k rows at once wouldnt really be a good idea anyways. i will cache the list of ids instead of the the whole table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

create a table with your ID's, then join to table, ordering by another identity column.

Presumably if you have 10k id's they will not be manually entered, so prehaps able to build sort/join table in a different way. SHould also be more efficient than using large `in`

```
create table #tempID(idSort int identity(1,1), id int)
insert into #tempID(id)
select 12 union all
select 6 union all
select 4 union all
select 3 union all
select 13 

select * from table t1
    inner join #tempID t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
order by t2.idSort
```

To create sort table dynamically, you need this function (or similar):

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[comma_sep_var_intSort] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (idSort int identity(1,1), id int NOT NULL 
) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (id)
         VALUES (cast(substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen) as int))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
  RETURN
END
```

Then join like this:

```
declare @idList varchar(max)

set @idLIst = '12,6,4,3,13'

    select * from table t1
        inner join [dbo].[comma_sep_var_int](@idList) t2
            on t1.id = t2.id
    order by t2.idSort
```

Comment: If you want it dynamic, you probably need a function.